# Change SSRS parameter value into column name in query

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I am trying to, without stored procedures, create a SQL query in an SSRS report and take a parameter value and use it as a column name.  My question is how to I change the parameter value into the actual column name?  I have tried the following query with the table identifier (i.e. t.@FilterColumn1) and without the table identifier (i.e. @FilterColumn1).

```
DECLARE @FilterColumn1 AS nvarchar(250)
SET @FilterColumn1 = 'Column1'
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.@FilterColumn1
FROM [JetNavDwh2017].[dbo].[TableName] t WITH(NOLOCK)
```

When I do not use the table identifier the result is the the column name I defined.  When I use the table identifier I receive the error message below, but I have not found a conclusive way to resolve the issue based on the error.  Thank you in advance for your help!

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near '@FilterColumn1'.
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: In sql is not allowed the use of var for db object as  column  or table's name

Comment: You can actually build your dataset query, the actual sql statement, dynamically within SSRS and use the report parameters in that query. If you would like an answer based on this approach let me know by commenting here I will post an example later tonight.

Comment: sounds like you need a `dynamic query` .. the other way is mickey mouse.. where in the report you hide the columns not selected